# Why does this minimal filter return no results at all?

Tags: support, api, filter

I tried to create a 'minimal' filter

> https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions#order=desc&sort=activity&filter=!34JvAEfIUyU-&site=stackoverflow&run=true

for the 'question' object, which was:

original_question -> question_id
original_question -> title
question -> body
question -> body_markdown
question -> question_id
question -> score

but I only get `{}`.

Do I need to include specific fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every response from the API contains a wrapper, with information about potential errors, your daily quota, and the actual results, which are in the `items` field. If you check that box:

[image]

and hit Save, you will get what you want:

https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions#order=desc&sort=activity&filter=!)fHr9OrJY1xA0I-&site=stackoverflow&run=true